# Render HTML elements with perspective?

Tags: html, css, matrix, perspective

The goal is to render HTML elements with perspective, as in the examples below.

We tried using CSS `skew` transformations, but those didn't look right as they warped the element's aspect ratio or otherwise created distortions.

Here are CSS skew transformations we tried. None of these look as good as the examples below.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMzdPx

```
transform: skew(20deg, -15deg);

transform: skew(45deg, -25deg);

transform: skew(45deg, -30deg);
```

How can you achieve this kind of perspective rendering of HTML elements?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just use a 3D transform?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the `perspective` property in CSS ?
 https://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/dxGTL/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48777549/8620333

Comment: @AllanJebaraj Might be worth noting, `perspective` is only partially compatible in IE

Answer (score 12):

As you said, use perspective combined with some rotation

```css
img {
  width:150px;
  margin:20px;
}
img.first {
  transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(20deg);
}
img.last {
  transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="first">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="last">
```

```css
img {
  width:150px;
  margin:30px;
  transform:perspective(500px)  rotateY(15deg) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" >
```

Related question for more details:

[CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51891329/8620333)

Comment: I’m not sure whether the asker wants [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)) or [parallel projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection). The above code examples use perspective projection, but if you want parallel projection instead, you can just change `perspective(500px)` to `perspective(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this.
I used CSS custom properties, to make the calculation a little bit more obvious.

Please note:
The order of the transform properties is very important. It is evaluated from right to left:

From [MDN transform CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Values)

> The transform functions are multiplied in order from left to right, meaning that composite transforms are effectively applied in order from right to left.

That means, `transform: rotateX(90deg) translateX(100px)` is not the same as `transform: translateX(100px) rotateX(90deg)`. The former first translates and then rotates while the latter does the rotation before the translations.

```css
.box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 268px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/100/136/276);
}
.box:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/200/136/276);
}
.box:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/300/136/276);
}
.box:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/400/136/276);
}

.container {
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-35deg) translate3d(-100px, -200px, -500px);
}

.skew {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  --width: 140px;
  --height: 278px;
  --x: 0;
  --y: 0;
  --offsetX: calc(var(--x) * var(--width));
  --offsetY: calc(var(--y) * var(--height));
  transform: translate(var(--offsetX), var(--offsetY));
}
.skew:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  --x: -2;
}
.skew:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  --x: -1;
}
.skew:nth-child(5n + 3) {
  --x: 0;
}
.skew:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  --x: 1;
}
.skew:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  --x: 2;
}
.skew:nth-child(n + 1):nth-child(-n + 5) {
  --y: -2;
}
.skew:nth-child(n + 6):nth-child(-n + 10) {
  --y: -1;
}
.skew:nth-child(n + 11):nth-child(-n + 15) {
  --y: 0;
}
.skew:nth-child(n + 16):nth-child(-n + 20) {
  --y: 1;
}
.skew:nth-child(n + 21):nth-child(-n + 25) {
  --y: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
  <div class="skew box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the element so to speak. The following from your codepen:
Changed html:

```
<div class="perspective">
<div class="skew">
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

changed css:

```
.perspective {
position: relative;
-webkit-perspective: 1242px; /* Safari 4-8 */
perspective: 1242px;
height: 2688px;
}

.front {
width: 1242px;
height: 2688px;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(-80em);
background: url(https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png);
}

.skew {
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(80deg);
height: 2560px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Still need sides and back added in the css, but you can paste this into your codepen and see how it is working.